# Node.js 6.10 HEX->BASE64->UTF8

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

My code generates "data" containing a json. I need to separate the HEX-value from the Buffer, and decode it from HEX->BASE64->UTF8 into a string.

Code:

```
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```
> { ContentType: 'application/json',   InvokedProductionVariant:
> 'AllTraffic',   Body: <Buffer 7b 22 73 63 6f 72 65 73 22 3a 5b 7b 22
> 73 63 6f 72 65 22 3a 32 2e 35 31 35 30 34 32 33 37 32 39 7d 5d 7d> }
```

Code below works for base64 to utf8. But the steps inbetween I cannot figure out or find answer to.

```
Buffer.from("...", 'base64').toString('utf8'));
```

Comment: Wherever you getting the data, it already looks like a buffer.  So have you tried -> `data.toString('utf8')`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When trying console.log(data.toString('utf8') it outputs "[object Object]"?

Comment: Sorry  `console.log(data.Body.toString('utf8'))`

Comment: Worked like a charm! If you want to add it as an answer I will flag it accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data object's Body, is already Buffer, so all you need to do is convert that buffer.

```
console.log(data.Body.toString('utf8'));
```

Looks like this is JSON, so even better would be ->

```
const ret = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString('utf8'));
console.log(ret.scores[0].score);
```